# Proper method for stopping backgroundworker before form dispose

Tags: c#, forms, backgroundworker

In my application I'm using child forms where the user have to fill some data into textboxes then click 'OK' or 'Cancel'. To prevent okaying with empty fields, I'd like to use a backgroundworker which would monitor the fields and keep the 'OK' button disabled until all fields are filled. The code is (almost) working but throws exception when the child form is disposed, probably because the bgw is still running but the form has already disposed. How can I stop the bgw properly?

```
    private void FormRecSettings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tb_recdatetime.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_";

        backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker2.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker2_DoWork);


        btn_ok.Enabled = false;
        if (backgroundWorker2.IsBusy != true)
        {
            backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
       while(true)
       {
            if ((backgroundWorker2.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }


            if (tb_recsuffix.Text.Length > 0 && tb_filename.Text.Length > 0)
                SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(btn_ok, "Enabled", true);

            else SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(btn_ok, "Enabled", false);
        }

    }


    public static void SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(Control control, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        {
            control.Invoke(new SetControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate(SetControlPropertyThreadSafe), new object[] { control, propertyName, propertyValue });
        }
        else
        {
            control.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, control, new object[] { propertyValue });
        }
    }

    private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
        {
            backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
        }


        string mm, inv;

        if (rbtn_UK.Checked == true) mm = "UK";
        else mm = "DE";

        if (rbtn_invyes.Checked == true) inv = "Yes";
        else inv = "No";

        // instance the event args and pass it each value
        NewRecUpdateEventArgs args = new NewRecUpdateEventArgs(tb_recsuffix.Text, tb_filename.Text, mm,
                                                                    inv);

        // raise the event with the updated arguments

        NewRecUpdated(this, args);

        this.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but in my opinion a `BackgroundWorker` is overkill and will probably give you more problems then joy.

I suggest to hook up the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` and do the check there whether the buttons can be enabled or not.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        c.TextChanged += tb_TextChanged;
    }
}
```

Event handler:

```
private void tb_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
            {
                this.okButton.Enabled = false;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    this.okButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Agreed, I now think that it can be done a way easier but anyway it is always good to learn something.

Comment: Thank you. I've implemented  your example and it is working great. However, I keep the topic open just to learn more on the bgw method.

Comment: I don't see you calling the bgw for a second time, but the actual work doesn't seem very long-taking too me, so I wonder why it didn't end yet.

Comment: I see you call `this.Dispose();` on the end of the button event handler. You shouldn't.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, somehow the while loop was left out. Corrected the doWork function.

Comment: Also, put `if (!this.IsDisposed || this.Disposing)` in the `DoWork`.

Comment: And if you do such a loop, don't forget to put in a `Thread.Sleep(500)` to prevent 100% cpu usage and slowing down your application massively.

Answer (score 0):

Updated my doWork function based on Patrick's hints and it seems to be working fine now (see below). However, Patrick's textchanged event based solution is better.

```
    void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if ((backgroundWorker2.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            if (!this.IsDisposed || this.Disposing)
            {
                if (tb_recsuffix.Text.Length > 0 && tb_filename.Text.Length > 0)
                    SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(btn_ok, "Enabled", true);

                else SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(btn_ok, "Enabled", false);
            }

            Thread.Sleep(500);

        }

    }
```